# Stuck at Nodejs HTTP responses in single request

Tags: node.js

I am stuck at my project Need to Take all the responses at ones one single request means all api end point when Right now there are select option all instance are running in switich case according to the select option value i want to change in only on single submit i will get all response ("https://smartcar.com/docs/api?language=cURL#get-all-vehicle 
 s("Link")

```
    app.post('/request', async (req, res,next) => {




    app.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
      const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
      return Promise.map(_.keys(vehicles), (id) => {
        const instance = new smartcar.Vehicle(id, access.accessToken);
        return instance.disconnect();
      })
        .finally(() => {
          req.session = null;
          res.redirect('/');
        });

      });


     */
    app.get('/callback', function(req, res, next) {
      const code = _.get(req, 'query.code');
      if (!code) {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }

      // Exchange authorization code for access token
      client.exchangeCode(code)
        .then(function(access) {
          req.session = {};
          req.session.vehicles = {};
          req.session.access = access;
          return res.redirect('/vehicles');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          const message = err.message || `Failed to exchange authorization code for access token`;
          const action = 'exchanging authorization code for access token';
          return redirectToError(res, message, action);
        });

    });

    /**
     * Renders a list of vehicles. Lets the user select a vehicle and type of
     * request, then sends a POST request to the /request route.
     */


    app.get('/vehicles', function(req, res, next) {
      const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
      if (!access) {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
      const {accessToken} = access;
      smartcar.getVehicleIds(accessToken)
        .then(function(data) {
          const vehicleIds = data.vehicles;
          const vehiclePromises = vehicleIds.map(vehicleId => {
            const vehicle = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, accessToken);
            req.session.vehicles[vehicleId] = {
              id: vehicleId,
            };
            return vehicle.info();
          });


    /**
     * Triggers a request to the vehicle and renders the response.
     */

    app.post('/request', async (req, res,next) => {

    const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
    if (!access) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }

    const {vehicleId, requestType: type} = req.body;
    const vehicle = vehicles[vehicleId];
    const instance = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, access.accessToken);





      instance.info()
          .then((data) =>{
            res.render('dash' ,{data, type, vehicle})

          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle info.';
            const action = 'fetching vehicle info';
            return redirectToError(res, message, action);
          })


    // console.log(instance.info())

     })
    app.post('/request', function(req, res, next) {
      const {access, vehicles} = req.session;
      if (!access) {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }

      const {vehicleId, requestType: type} = req.body;
      const vehicle = vehicles[vehicleId];
      const instance = new smartcar.Vehicle(vehicleId, access.accessToken);

      let data = null;

      switch(type) {
        case 'info':
          instance.info()
            .then(data => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle info.';
              const action = 'fetching vehicle info';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
        case 'location':
          instance.location()
            .then(({data}) => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle location.';
              const action = 'fetching vehicle location';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
        case 'odometer':
          instance.odometer()
            .then(({data}) => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle odometer.';
              const action = 'fetching vehicle odometer';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
           case 'charge':
          instance.charge()
            .then(({data}) => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vehicle odometer.';
              const action = 'charge';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
           case 'battery':
          instance.battery()
            .then(({data}) => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get battery.';
              const action = 'battery';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
          case 'vin':
          instance.vin()
            .then(({data}) => res.render('data', {data, type, vehicle}))
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to get vin details.';
              const action = 'vin';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
        case 'lock':
          instance.lock()
            .then(function() {
              res.render('data', {
                // Lock and unlock requests do not return data if successful
                data: {
                  action: 'Lock request sent.',
                },
                type,
                vehicle,
              });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to send lock request to vehicle.';
              const action = 'locking vehicle';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
        case 'unlock':
          instance.unlock()
            .then(function() {
              res.render('data', {
                vehicle,
                type,
                // Lock and unlock requests do not return data if successful
                data: {
                  action: 'Unlock request sent.',
                },
              });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              const message = err.message || 'Failed to send unlock request to vehicle.';
              const action = 'unlocking vehicle';
              return redirectToError(res, message, action);
            });
          break;
        default:
          return redirectToError(
            res,
            `Failed to find request type ${requestType}`,
            'sending request to vehicle'
          );
      }

    });

    app.listen(PORT, function() {
      console.log(`smartcar-demo server listening on port ${PORT}`);
      opn(`http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to run all requests in parallel. Here is how it can be done.

```js
const saveRequest = () => {
  const info = instance.info();
  const loc = instance.location();
  const odometer = instance.odometer();
  
  Promise.all([info, loc, odometer])
    .then(results => {
      return res.render('dash', {results})
    })
    .catch(err => err);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i figure it out

```
const saveRequest = async() => {
  const info = await instance.info();
  const loc = await instance.location();
  const odometer = await instance.odometer()
  return{
    info:info,
    location:loc,
    odometer:odometer
  }
}
saveRequest()
.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  return res.render('dash' ,{data})

})
```

Or someone can suggest me a better way or point out the mistake it can be very helpfull It is working fine for me